Сайт не доступен в РФ регионе, но доступен в РБ (Timeweb Cloud). Какие причины ошибки?
Сайт 82.97.249.164:5000 не доступен в России (ошибка "во время загрузки страницы соединение с сервером было сброшено" на скрине), в Белорусском регионе все работает корректно. VPN все решает, но это не выход.

Сайт размещен на timeweb.cloud
Сервер перезагружать пробовал, порт открыт.
Поднимается через Docker:


FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
USER $APP_UID
WORKDIR /app
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5000
EXPOSE 5000

# Этот этап используется для сборки проекта службы
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Directory.Packages.props", "."]
COPY ["NuGet.Config", "."]
COPY ["OzonOrdersWeb/OzonOrdersWeb.csproj", "OzonOrdersWeb/"]
COPY ["OzonRepositories/OzonRepositories.csproj", "OzonRepositories/"]
COPY ["OzonDomains/OzonDomains.csproj", "OzonDomains/"]
COPY ["AppRepository/Servcies.csproj", "AppRepository/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./OzonOrdersWeb/OzonOrdersWeb.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/OzonOrdersWeb"
RUN dotnet build "./OzonOrdersWeb.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

# Этот этап используется для публикации проекта службы, который будет скопирован на последний этап
FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./OzonOrdersWeb.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

# Этот этап используется в рабочей среде или при запуске из VS в обычном режиме (по умолчанию, когда конфигурация отладки не используется)
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "OzonOrdersWeb.dll"]



Подскажите причины ошибки и пути решения.

Причём тут вообще докер, если проблема сетевая?

Имеет смысл обратиться в техподдержку провайдера

Если б можно было не пользоваться VPN, так и не пользовались бы. Не к докеру надо с этим вопросом и не к провайдеру, а куды повыше, вплоть до Самого.
